# Getting an error from "Pub get" on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I recently updated dart and flutter and after that I am getting this error when trying
Pug Get:

```
C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.113.3]: errno=Unknown error

exit code: 128
pub finished with exit code 69
Process finished with exit code 69
```

I am not sure how to fix this? thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm facing same issue after upgrading the flutter

Answer (score 10):

There is an issue with the URL to one of the packages in your pubspec. You can see more info on which repository is giving the error by running `flutter pub get -v`.

This occurred to me as [Github has removed](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) git native transport via git://. I had to change my git pubspec entries to

```
package_name:
  git: 
    url: https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html.git
```

Comment: could you please give step by step to solve this, I'm beginner

Answer (score -1):

`flutter pub upgrade`

`flutter pub get`

These command needs to be run from inside a project folder, not from inside the folder `flutter\bin\`, where the flutter installation lives.

Comment: So I just tried to run them from the project folder and I am still getting the same error:

"PS C:\Users\nitza\StudioProjects\Swiper> flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.113.4]: errno=Unknown error

exit code: 128
pub finished with exit code 69
PS C:\Users\nitza\StudioProjects\Swiper> flutter pub get
Git error. Command: `git fetch`
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.114.4]: errno=Unknown error

exit code: 128"